How do I get CSS properties in application.css to be applied to pages in my Rails app?
This is one of those issues where either I'm missing a semicolon or the whole point.
I am making a Rails app in 7.1.3.2.
And I can't get css properties to apply to my view.
I created the app with
% rails new --database=postgresql --name=myapp

My ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css file is:
(comments snipped)
= require_tree .
= require_self
body {background-color: teal;}

My ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb is:
  <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1> The time is </h1>
   <%= Time.now %>
  </body>
</html>

If I go to localhost:3000/assets/application.css?body=1, I can see
(comments snipped)
= require_tree .
= require_self
body {background-color: teal;}

(this is somewhat odd, as application.css is in /assets/stylesheets not /assets ; but edits to the file show up immediately.)
If I go to localhost:3000, and view source, I see
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="xrgOl47LT8fz9UPdAoP85ierdQVWyqirwYQ0nJZW0RdPqrOOSNRvz8Xy9WXxw-8C-Q27v55aR8TNysfVEoZ6mA"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-1a92102f03589ed75926c49624344892f7d000b3e5a3b6f98056e7c26efc8a33.css" data-turbo-track="reload"/>
    <script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
      "imports": {
        "application": "/assets/application-37f365cbecf1fa2810a8303f4b6571676fa1f9c56c248528bc14ddb857531b95.js",
        "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-918a6cf2f2be8ed9555c9a11eee69c7dc2f01770802815576efc931876b327fb.js",
        "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js",
        "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js",
        "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
        "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js",
        "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js"
      }
    }</script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/application-37f365cbecf1fa2810a8303f4b6571676fa1f9c56c248528bc14ddb857531b95.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/turbo.min-918a6cf2f2be8ed9555c9a11eee69c7dc2f01770802815576efc931876b327fb.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/controllers/index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js">
    <script type="module">
    import "application"
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> The time is </h1>

       2024-05-05 14:56:48 +0100
      
</body>
</html>


which tells me the css has been included into the page, correct?

And I can see the application.css (with its fingerprint rename) under the assets in the web inspector

But! My background isn't teal.

(for the avoidance of doubt, I won't have a teal background - just testing some visible css property.  :-) )
Have I missed something somewhere? I think I am using Sprocket, and the gem is in my Gemfile. I did have some css files in the stylesheets folder, which did seem to be being picked up but also not applied, so I've simplified things down.

In sources there is <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-1, so css is attached, did you try to check actual css for body tag in source? did yo try to use css like body {background: #000;} ?

Thanks! I just tried body {background: #000;} - no change.

Should I expect to see the css in the source view if it's working, as opposed to just the link. I don't see any.

This is not a valid css and body style never gets applied:
= require_tree .
= require_self
body {background-color: teal;}

requre_self and require_tree are sprockets directives, you supposed to have them inside of the top comment:
/*
 * = require_tree .
 * = require_self
 */

body {background-color: teal;}



application.css is in /assets/stylesheets not /assets ; but edits to the file show up immediately

/assets is a route added by sprockets-rails, it really has nothing to do with app/assets directory. You can only load files directly from public directory, so assets would load from public/assets/ if you have them precompiled. In development, sprockets compiles assets on the fly so it still works even though your public/assets is empty.

Thanks! I had assumed erroneously I needed to uncomment the directives. But commenting them hasn't changed anything yet.

And thanks for the explanation on /assets  - that makes sense.

OK - got it working. Turns out I had run  rails assets:precompile  in an attempt to get it working - and of course that had populated my public/assets folder, so no further changes to the actual assets were being registered. Once I deleted the files and restarted the server, Alex's fix to the sprockets directives is what made everything work as expected. Thankyou, and thanks also to @AntonBogdanov  for making me check the source more carefully so that I noticed the fingerprint wasn't updating!

So - it was the metaphorical missing semicolon, not a wholesale misunderstanding !
